# Doctrine - run custom query on one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a couple of entities, `Food` and `GroupsOption` which has `one-to-many` relationships that mean each food could have nothing or many groups option. in my below query, I want to filter foods which have not any groups option. Here is my code:

```
    $result = $qb->select(
            "partial Food.{
                foodId, 
                foodName
            }",
        ->from($this->entityClass, "Food")
        ->leftJoin("Food.groupsOption", "OptionGroup")
        ->addSelect("OptionGroup")
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

The result of the above query like this :

```
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => Food {#
    .
    .
    .
     #groupsOption: PersistentCollection {#1157
        -snapshot: array:1 [ …1]
        -owner: Food {#1065}
        -association: array:15 [ …15]
        -em: EntityManager {#272 …11}
        -backRefFieldName: "food"
        -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#1112 …}
        -isDirty: false
        #collection: ArrayCollection {#1158
          -elements: array:1 [
             .
             .
             .
        ]
    ]
    1 => Food {#
      .
      .
      .
      #groupsOption: PersistentCollection {#1383
        -snapshot: []
        -owner: Food {#1371}
        -association: array:15 [ …15]
        -em: EntityManager {#272 …11}
        -backRefFieldName: "food"
        -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#1112 …}
        -isDirty: false
        #collection: ArrayCollection {#1382
          -elements: []
        }
        #initialized: true
      }
    ]
```

It gives me all result, but I just wanted to change it to what I said before.

Any suggestion?